# PhpStorm watch changes and upload to remote server

Tags: upload, phpstorm

Is it possible to tell PhpStorm to watch a file and if the file is changed (like compiling from scss to css) PhpStorm will automatically upload the compiled css file to the remote server?

---

**Solution** is "Upload external changes" under "Deployment Options".
its uploading my compiled file automatically if I am work around the scss files.

Comment: Have a look at this https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Sync+changes+and+automatic+upload+to+a+deployment+server+in+PhpStorm ((optional) 2. Automatic Upload section)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is done from the "Deployment" section in Phpstorm > Settings (see the screenshot). Take a look at the instructions here: [Deploying PHP Applications with PhpStorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deploying+PHP+applications+with+PhpStorm).

It involves:

1. Configuring a deployment server (see 1.1 - 1.3)
2. Uploading a file to the server (see 3).

Once the server is set up, you can Upload files manually:

> Tools > Deployment > Upload to Default Server

Or automatically:

> Tools > Deployment > Automatic Upload

I prefer using the manual upload option (with a hotkey) to have more control.

In the screenshot, my deployment server is a local XAMPP htdocs folder on my mac. Your configuration will be different, but it's the same concept.

[image: Setting up a deployment server in PhpStorm]

Comment: Setting up a file watcher for SASS is another topic, but you can do that from Settings > File Watchers. There are some posts about it on SO or you can read  https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html